# Change a css selector only for the home page in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am making my first steps learning to code. I decided to make a wordpress theme so like this I can continue learning from the practice.

In the Twentysixteen theme there is a selector called .img to modify all the images in the theme. I want to modify this selector only for the homepage and I can't achieve it. I don't know if it's possible.

I tryied to make this but it doesn't work:

```
.home .img {
height: auto;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
}
```

Do you have some suggestion?

Comment: Add custom class or id in those images which you are adding on homepage then you can access them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a class to that image, or to a parent div in homepage (you can do it by modifying the PHP files if the homepage doesn't already have an ID or a class).
Then you can run the exact code you tried already.

Answer (score 0):

In your custom theme, have you added `body_class()` function to your opening body tag:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

If you have, every page will have a unique class in their body tag. For the homepage, it'll be "page-home", "page-front-page" or something similar.

You can then use that unique class, which is unique to that page only, to style the classes / elements on that page only:

```
.page-home .class {
    Styles here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom id or class to your element, and then select that class/id in your css.

```
#my_custom_id {
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    }
```